# How to check if number is summation of powers of 5

Tags: algorithm, math, numbers

How to check if a number is a power of 5?

I could think of below algorithm. Is there way to improve it? Any mathematical trick?

1. First check if last digit is 5.
2. If last digit is 5; divide it by 5.
   If result of division is 1, then number is power of 5.
   Else check if division result itself is power of 5 (i.e. go to step 1 with result as number).

Comment: Look at this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22580/how-to-check-if-a-integer-is-a-power-of-some-integer

Comment: @mat what is your suggestion to ? Remove step and what to do ?  What do you mean by off-topic.  If you know any specific documentation just point to it. That will help than such comments.

Comment: > Any mathematical trick?
Your algorithm seems to be valid, unless you want to code in Assembly language and need optimizations.
How big can the input be? Thousands of digits, sent in a text file?

Comment: @TimothyHa  number can be very big or small. I am more inclined to know of better solution than my almost-primitive approach.

Comment: Your algorithm won't work if numbers are with thousands of digits, not fitting into INT or LONG as in Pham Trung's answer.  And also taking logarithm could be a problem.

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to look at individual digits, you can just do it like this:

```
n = (int)(log(x) / log(5)); // get n = log5(x), truncated to integer
if (pow(5, n) == x)         // test to see whether x == 5^n
    // x is a power of 5
```

[<kbd>LIVE DEMO</kbd>](http://ideone.com/6MYwO9)

Comment: That sounds good. However from programming/algorithm perspective "log" method may not be available in every  language.

Comment: True - I don't know of any modern language that doesn't have basic math functions like `log`, `pow`, etc, but you never know. And of course you can always implement your own versions if the language does not support them.

Answer (score 4):

There are only few power of five that fit in int/long range, so you just need to generate all of them and check one by one (less than 60 numbers), using a HashSet will have O(1) time complexity

Comment: My CS professor used to give me numbers in big files, not as int or long.

Comment: @TimothyHa so in HashSet you can keep strings, BigNums or whatever representation (like hash, module arithmetic...). However, you can check it easy in O(lg n), without storing the results. Look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26869655/2349936). Pham Trung: +1, for writing about O(1) solution (after preprocessing).

Answer (score 3):

Successive division until you reach the number undivided by 5 and check whether the result is equal to 1, isn't bad solution. It take log_5(n) operations, so it's O(lg n), it's very good time. For `9094947017729282379150390625` it's only 40 operations!

Comment: what is **n** here in this runtime?

Comment: It's number to check. (Assumption was that divide by 5 has O(1) complexity. It's obviously wrong for numbers with millions of digits, but any algorithm has that problem, so I skipped that.) Including size of number it will be near O(lg^2 n).

Answer (score -1):

What I would do is first create an array of numbers that are powers of 5. You could use a range, and then say, for each value in the range, take that value to the fifth power, and push the new value into the array.

You would then find if n, the number you are looking for is included in the array.